Time Cost of UNNEST operation in query?
This is for PrestoSQL
Assuming col1, col2, col3 are of same cardinality, and assuming the Table has N rows
 SELECT c1 from Table, UNNEST(col1) AS t(c1) 


 SELECT c1, c2 from Table, UNNEST(col1, col2) AS t(c1, c2) 


 SELECT c1, c2, c3 from Table, UNNEST(col1, col2, col3) AS t(c1, c2, c3) 

How would the time complexities for these three queries differ? Would the 3rd one be N^3 times more costly than first one, and 2nd one be N^2 times more costly than the first one in terms of time complexity?
How does time complexity be measured in terms of column cardinality, and the table size?

Which dbms are you using? UNNEST isn't widely implemented.

unnest with multiple parameters certainly isn't widely implemented, is it Postgres?

@jarlh
this is for PrestoSQL, edited in the question. thanks.


How would the time complexities for these three queries differ? Would the 3rd one be N^3 times more costly than first one, and 2nd one be N^2 times more costly than the first one in terms of time complexity?

While without looking into the source code it is hard to claim anything, there is no reason for such operation to be power of N (number of rows in the table), unnest with multiple array columns will result in arrays matched on the index, so in terms of the time complexity it does not matter 1,2 or 3 array columns are used, it will be O(N*m) where m is average cardinality of the array per row (or if all rows has array columns with the same cardinality then O(N*m) where m is just a cardinality).
But for sure the query will be more time consuming since you are returning more data, but not an exponential in terms of number of array columns used.

Shouldn't m be the maximum cardinality, rather than average? The result is matched indicies up to the largest array length, with the rest getting nulls in those columns.

@Charlieface  In general case - yes. I've meant across the rows (OP suggests to consider cardinalities in the same row to be equal).

@GuruStron I'm sorry to bother you again. I posted another question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79082863/multiple-join-operations-on-the-same-columns-with-the-same-criteria-is-there-a, which is about query optimization. Could you take a look if you have some time? You've been helping me tons. thanks.
