Multiple Join Operations on the same columns with the same criteria. Is there a way to make this more efficient?
In Presto/Hive SQL, I have multiple tables, say T1, T2, T3, T4, X1, X2, X3, X4
Assume that the table size is
 T1 > T2 > T3 > T4
 X1 > X3 > X4 > X4

We have
SELECT 
    T1.a, T2.b, T3.c, T4.d 
FROM
    T1 
JOIN 
    T2 ON T1.userid = T2.userid AND T1.catch = T2.catch 
JOIN
    T3 ON T2.userid = T3.userid AND T2.catch = T3.catch 
JOIN
    T4 ON T3.userid = T4.userid AND T3.catch = T4.catch

Assuming column a only exists in T1, b only exists in T2, c only exists in T3, d only exists in T4. We have multiple join operations with the same conditions (columns userid, catch equal)
Also, for X1, X2, X3, X4, we have
 SELECT X1.f, X2.g, X3.h, X4.k 
 FROM X1 
 JOIN X2 ON X1.userid = X2.userid AND X1.time >= X2.time 
 JOIN X3 ON X2.userid = X3.userid AND X2.time >= X3.time 
 JOIN X4 ON X3.userid = X4.userid AND X3.time >= X4.time

Assuming column f only exists in X1, g only exists in X2, h only exists in X3, k only exists in X4. We have multiple join operations with the same conditions (columns userid equal, time of current table >= time of next joining table).
We have multiple join operations with the same conditions on the same columns.
Is there any way to make these queries less expensive? What would be the best solution if we wanna minimize the query time?
Any intermediate table would help to optimize the overall query?? For instance, if I join T1 with T2 and call it J1, and join T3 with T4 and call it J2 and join J1 with J2 with the same criteria, would it be quicker?
I heard indexing could help, but wasn't sure how that could be applied here. (any examples)?
tried to create some intermediate tables or way to reduce join operations, but couldn't come up with anything good. wanna check if any indexing approaches would be good.

Sounds like you just need an index (userid, catch) include (a/b/c/d) respectively for each table for the first query, and (userid, time) include (f/g/h/k) for the second. But honestly this question is far too vague to be answerable, we don't even know which DBMS you have and the queries don't look very representative. Please give us an actual query, with an actual query plan and actual table and existing index definitions, and maybe we can say something. SQL performance questions really don't have hand-wavy answers to them, we really need concrete info.

The joins with time >= are strange, the resultset will be huge anyway if there are many  records wit the same userid

None of your queries have a WHERE clause. Are you selecting the entire tables and then filtering? That's bound to be slow.

@TheImpaler Not necessarily: if the planner goes for one of the tables with the fewest matches first, and all tables are indexed properly, then the query will be very fast because the joins will eliminate early.

@Charlieface The thing is that this is not a "transactional query", but a "reporting query". I would agree with you that, as a reporting query, it could be not that slow under some conditions.

Please tag this with the RDMBS you're using (MySQL, MariaDB, SQL-Server, Oracle, etc.). Optimization is very implementation-dependent.

Equi-joining on the same columns
When joining three or more tables on the very same columns on equality (=) there are two scenarios:

All tables (maybe except one) are 1:1 related. We do this sometimes in order to give different grants on different data parts belonging to the same entry (e.g. separating a supplier's address data from their contract data, because different departments maintain these different data parts). In that case we did this separation voluntarily at the cost of (slightly) longer query times. The effect on runtimes is usually not serious, because we would of course index all tables on these columns.
In spite of joining on the same columns, the tables are 1:n or even m:n related. We create thus a cartesian join. E.g. joining both a products's suppliers and the product's buyers to the product, thus combining every supplier with every buyer, thus creating all combinations. As you can imagine, this is a very rare case, so we should be okay with long run times on these rare occasions.

Non-Equi-joining on the same columns
Your second query, which doesn't use equi-joins, also leads to such a cartesian result, even building up some history. This query looks weird and should be a extremely special case that you might run only once or very, very seldom.
Speeding up queries
As long as the queries are properly written, as yours are, we don't speed them up by re-writing them. We only see to it that the database itself supports such queries. This is done by supplying the appropriate indexes or even partitioning the tables.
For your queries, you want an index on the join columns on every table. Thus the DBMS can quickly find rows that belong together and access the table rows in question. Or you even provide covering indexes that include the selected column, too. Thus, the DBMS finds that information in the index and doesn't have to access the table row.
The index would start with the columns that are used in the ON or WHERE clause and then add the other columns. E.g.:
CREATE INDEX idx1t1 ON t1 (userid, catch, a);
CREATE INDEX idx1x1 ON x1 (userid, time, f);

Or, better, if your database suports the syntax:
CREATE INDEX idx1t1 ON t1 (userid, catch) INCLUDE (a);
CREATE INDEX idx1x1 ON x1 (userid, time) INCLUDE (f);

If, however, the queries were poorly written, which is sometimes seen with joins producing a cartesian product that is dealt with SELECT DISTINCT to get rid of the duplicates that the query itself produced, then it is the query that would have to get adjusted. Sometimes this is about using EXISTS or IN instead of a join, sometimes it is about aggreation before joining instead of vice versa, and sometimes lateral joins offer a good solution. But all this isn't the case in the queries you have shown.
And no, working with temporary tables usually rather slows things down than speeding them up. Their benefit is that they can make the process clearer, because tasks are diveded into separate queries. But each query takes its time, and the total time is usually longer than using a single query for the same task.

Optimization depends on the optimizer which is the most important module in the query engine.
The optimization level will therefore depend on the manufacturing secrets that major publishers do not share with free tools such as PostGreSQL, MySQL/MariaDB or SQLite...
For example, in your specific case and provided that you have implemented all the constraints necessary for the relational modeling of the database, some simplifications can be carried out by the optimizer (you do not give the DDL of your tables, so it is not possible to help you further on this point).
Secondly, indexes can greatly help performance provided that they are covering.
For your theoretical query, the necessary indexes would be as follows:
CREATE INDEX X1 ON T1 (userid, catch) INCLUDE (a);
CREATE INDEX X2 ON T2 (userid, catch) INCLUDE (b);
CREATE INDEX X3 ON T3 (userid, catch) INCLUDE (c);
CREATE INDEX X4 ON T4 (userid, catch) INCLUDE (d);

NOTE:

Syntax possible only on Microsoft SQL Server and PostgreSQL
You must study the order of the columns of the index key, either (userid, catch) or the opposite (catch, userid) so that the head column is as discriminating as possible. But the order of this key must be the same for the different indexes

They will be all the more efficient if the index is compressed:
naturally by the indexing algorithm by a compression in addition to the index type.
For example, this can be a HASH type index (PostGreSQL, MS SQL Server) or better still a vertical indexing (columnar, like the COLUMNSTORE of SQL Server.
This can also be a compression added to the index like that supported by SQL Server (DATA_COMPRESSION = ROW / PAGE).
PostGreSQL does not support any means of compressing the relational data of the indexes neither internally to the index nor by an external algorithm.
Finally, a last possibility to greatly improve the execution speed is parallelism. For example, in SQL Server, parallelism is automatic and as soon as the optimizer detects an expensive query, it re-examines the execution plan of the query from the multithreading perspective and if this option proves beneficial, the executed plan will be multithreaded.
PostGreSQL has some parallelism possibilities, but it is still embryonic and not very efficient due to the process model that the PostGreSQL staff wanted to change to threading...
https://lwn.net/ml/pgsql-hackers/31cc6df9-53fe-3cd9-af5b-ac0d801163f4@iki.fi/
